# React input cursor position moves to the end?

Tags: reactjs

I came across with this scenario where I want to "sanitize" the input before calling onChange, however even without re-render, the cursor moves to the end. why?

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  state = { value: this.props.value };

  onChange = e => {
    let nextValue = e.target.value;

    if (!/[0-9]/.test(nextValue)) {
      this.setState({ value: nextValue });
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Input value="type something here" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I can guess why this is happening but what I really want to say is that this approach is poor UX and the issue can be avoided all together. You should allow the user to type whatever in the field and show some type of validation error indicators (red border, message, etc). If I type a number and nothing happens my first thought is going to be that I didn't hit the key, my keyboard is having issues, or your form is broken, rather than thinking some type of hidden validation is occurring.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but there is a lot of use cases for what I'm doing, specially for "mask input" like phone, credit card, date input

Answer (score 0):

You can use onKeyPress to sanitize an input before onChange, without "side effects".

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/9jlm59n52r

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Input extends React.Component {
  state = { value: this.props.value };

  handleKeyPress = e => {
    let keyPressed = e.key;

    if (/[0-9]/.test(keyPressed)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input value="type something here" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**EDIT:**

Sanitize input on paste:

```
handlePaste = e => {
  let pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

  if (/[0-9]/.test(pastedText)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

...

  <input
    ...
    onPaste={this.handlePaste}
    ...
  />
```

Comment: I tried that approach too, the issue is, now you can copy paste from some where else(by keyboard, mouse or dragging) :s